# Rig is deformed and larger then character when importing

Tags: modeling, import

Every time i import a rig from Sketchfab, the rig becomes deformed when imported. i am new and dont know how to fix this problem.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Select the rig, go to edit mode, change the pivot to "individual origins", select all bones and press S to scale them as desired.

You can even scale some of them only, as you like, as long as they are not connected each other (as the rig in your picture looks like).

Another way is to assign a custom viewport object to each bone, in pose mode, but scaling them in edit mode is the right choice to have a good starting point.

[image]